# Joomla 3 database SUM aggregate on a field and WHERE clause with GROUP BY plus HAVING

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I have this query in Joomla:

```
$query
->select($db->quoteName(array('#__session.session_id', '#__hikashop_cart.session_id', '#__hikashop_cart.cart_id', '#__hikashop_cart_product.product_id', '#__hikashop_product.product_parent_id', '#__hikashop_cart_product.cart_product_quantity')))
->from($db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart'))
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart_product') . ' ON #__hikashop_cart.cart_id = #__hikashop_cart_product.cart_id')
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__hikashop_product') . ' ON #__hikashop_cart_product.product_id = #__hikashop_product.product_id')
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__session') . ' ON #__hikashop_cart.session_id = #__session.session_id')
->where($db->quoteName('hady9_session.session_id').' = '.$db->quote($thesession).'AND ('.$db->quoteName('hady9_hikashop_product.product_parent_id').' = '.$db->quote('3578').'OR'.$db->quote('4482').'OR'.$db->quote('4947').'OR'.$db->quote('8047').'OR'.$db->quote('5102').'OR'.$db->quote('5257').'OR'.$db->quote('5412').'OR'.$db->quote('8202').'OR'.$db->quote('5567').'OR'.$db->quote('5722').'OR'.$db->quote('5877').'OR'.$db->quote('8357').'OR'.$db->quote('6032').'OR'.$db->quote('6187').'OR'.$db->quote('6342').'OR'.$db->quote('8512').')');
```

Which I need to change to something like this:

```
->select($db->quoteName(array('#__hikashop_product.product_parent_id', Sum('#__hikashop_cart_product.cart_product_quantity'))))
->from($db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart'))
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart_product') . ' ON #__hikashop_cart.cart_id = #__hikashop_cart_product.cart_id')
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__hikashop_product') . ' ON #__hikashop_cart_product.product_id = #__hikashop_product.product_id')
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__session') . ' ON #__hikashop_cart.session_id = #__session.session_id')
->where($db->quoteName('hady9_session.session_id').' = '.$db->quote($thesession))
->groupby($db->quoteName('#__hikashop_product.product_parent_id'))
->having($db->quoteName('#__hikashop_product.product_parent_id').' = '.$db->quote('3578').'OR'.$db->quote('4482').'OR'.$db->quote('4947').'OR'.$db->quote('8047').'OR'.$db->quote('5102').'OR'.$db->quote('5257').'OR'.$db->quote('5412').'OR'.$db->quote('8202').'OR'.$db->quote('5567').'OR'.$db->quote('5722').'OR'.$db->quote('5877').'OR'.$db->quote('8357').'OR'.$db->quote('6032').'OR'.$db->quote('6187').'OR'.$db->quote('6342').'OR'.$db->quote('8512').')');
```

The differences in the second one are: I need a SUM on the #__hikashop_cart_product.cart_product_quantity field, GROUP BY on the #__hikashop_product.product_parent_id field with a HAVING condition using the #__hikashop_product.product_parent_id as a bunch of possible numbers.

The query does what I need it to do when testing in phpmyadmin, but I am unsure of the proper syntax to make it work in joomla for the SUM, GROUP BY and HAVING parts.

I have modified this query to this:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('#__hikashop_product.product_parent_id', ('sum('.$db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart_product.cart_product_quantity').')'))));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart'));
$query->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__hikashop_cart_product') . ' ON #__hikashop_cart.cart_id = #__hikashop_cart_product.cart_id');
$query->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__hikashop_product') . ' ON #__hikashop_cart_product.product_id = #__hikashop_product.product_id');
$query->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__session') . ' ON #__hikashop_cart.session_id = #__session.session_id');
$query->where($db->quoteName('#__session.session_id').' = '.$db->quote($thesession));
$query->group($db->quote('#__hikashop_product.product_parent_id'));
$query->having($db->quote('#__hikashop_product.product_parent_id').' = '.$db->quote('3578').'OR'.$db->quote('4482').'OR'.$db->quote('4947').'OR'.$db->quote('8047').'OR'.$db->quote('5102').'OR'.$db->quote('5257').'OR'.$db->quote('5412').'OR'.$db->quote('8202').'OR'.$db->quote('5567').'OR'.$db->quote('5722').'OR'.$db->quote('5877').'OR'.$db->quote('8357').'OR'.$db->quote('6032').'OR'.$db->quote('6187').'OR'.$db->quote('6342').'OR'.$db->quote('8512').')');
```

I am getting this error atm:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`.`cart_product_quantity`)` FROM `hady9_hikashop_cart` INNER JOIN `hady9_hik' at line 1 SQL=SELECT......

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a normal $sql query without using Joomla's query layer. You can do this the following way (the below is an example):

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM #__content WHERE id='5'";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$result = $db->loadAssocList();
```

Comment: Why not use Joomla's database API? Also using your method, nothing is being escaped at all

Comment: If you check the code on many large extensions, you don't see them using the Joomla specific functions such as ->join and ->select and ->where, simply because complex queries are nearly impossible to write this way.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am a noob with this stuff. Using the joomla api (inserting the code into template using Flexi custom code module)  is the only way I have been able to get what I need to get working, working. The first query I posted above does work but I realised that I need the SUM, GROUP BY and HAVING stuff in there as well, hence the second query in OP. I have been trying to make something with a normal/standard sql query but I just can't get the hang of it.

Comment: The fact that many "large" extensions don't use the API is because a lot of them are still using legacy code from 1.5 or 1.0 even. If you are writing new you should use the API for portability and safety.